# Как правильно реализовать реф на Select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть компонент Material-UI [Stepper](https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#stepper). В первый Step вставлен компонент, внутри которого Select. При выборе значения в Select и переходе на следующий шаг, элементы из первого шага удаляются из DOM полностью. Если я хочу вернуться в предыдущий шаг, то в компоненте Select'a хранится предыдущее выбранное значение, но оно визуально не отображается в самом поле, т.е поле остается пустым. Нужно что-то придумать либо с рефами, чтобы компонент не удалялся из дерева полностью, либо что-то еще.

Код компонента с Select:

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" >
        <InputLabel id="demo-customized-select-label">
            Специалист
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
            className={classes.select}
            labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
            value={props.selectedMaster?.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            input={<BootstrapInput/>}
        >
            <MenuItem value={JSON.stringify(null)}>
                <Typography>
                   Все
                </Typography>
            </MenuItem>
            {props.masterList.map(masterData => {
                return (
                    <MenuItem key={masterData.id} value={JSON.stringify(masterData)}>
                        <Typography>
                            {masterData.name}
                        </Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                )
            })}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что ни `Material-UI` ни `Select` тут не причём. Как я понял, у вас теряется состояние при смене компонента? на чём компоненты(класс/ф-я) ? почему бы просто не прятать их `hidden` атрибутом?

Comment: @qwabra их убирает из дерева полностью компонент Stepper, когда мы переходим на следующий шаг. В принципе, решение логичное если нам не нужно возвращаться назад, но мне здесь это мешает. Все на функциональных компонентах.
В том то и дело, что состояние не теряется, т.е оно также пробрасывается в компонент Select, но вместо того чтобы отображать значение в поле ввода, там пустое поле

Comment: мм, я вас не понимаю.  компонент `Stepper` это библиотечный компонент? что за библиотека?

Comment: @qwabra, https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#stepper

Comment: укажите это в вопросе